# How to get loop count from mediaplayer Android

Tags: android, loops, audio, media-player

How to Get the number of completed loop value? I wanted to assign the value to `count`, so the users know how many times, the song had got repeated.
help me out,and thanks in advance.

```
int count=0;    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song1);
         mp.setLooping(true);
        playsound();
}
    public void playsound() {
    mp.start();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MediaPlayer doesnt have this feature. So to this you have to handle the looping by yourself. Disable the looping and use the following

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
    count++;
    player.seekTo(0);
    player.start();
}
```